# Examples of non-Human eating utensils in Star Trek

Tags: star-trek, aliens, episode-identification

The description of the everyday life of aliens is often very sparse and does not include their eating habits.

It occurs to me that there is at least one example of an alien eating tool that is not ordinary cutlery in Star Trek, but I cannot remember.

I am specifically after alien-invented utensils of any sort.

Comment: Is there a specific show or movie you're wondering about? The Original Series? The Next Generation? The new Kelvin movie series? Or are you asking about the whole Star Trek universe?

Comment: I think TNG, but cannot tell for sure.

Comment: while researching my answer, I was fascinated by how many alien cultures seemed to have (independently of humans) developed their own versions of forks and spoons. perhaps that's just a stage of evolution for most races, somewhere between the wheel and the warp drive.

Comment: @LevenTech Given that the modalities of alien eating in pretty well all Sc-Fi shows parallels that of Human eating modalities I don't think it's surprising that utensils are either Human designed or look like Human utensils.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Klingons (sometimes) use a 2-pronged skewer called a '[**puq chonnaQ**](http://klingonska.org/canon/1998-05-05a-news.txt)'.

**Although they don't have a name in the screenplay, Mark Okrand identifies the Klingon word for 'fork' as "*puq chonnaQ*", literally translated as a *"child's hunting spear"*.**

---

In Season 2, Episode 8 (*A Matter of Honor*), Riker sits down to eat with the crew of the *Pagh*, a Klingon vessel. Most of the Klingons are simply using their hands, but some of them (and Riker) are using these 2-pronged "skewers".

The Klingons were quite advanced (warp-capable, at least) before they ever encountered Humans, so it's likely they invented these skewers before learning about Human forks.

[image: image of Klingon and Riker eating with two-pronged skewers]

Comment: There isn't a name for them in the screenplay; http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/134.txt

Comment: @Valorum Based on [this newsgroup post by Marc Okrond](http://klingonska.org/canon/1998-05-05a-news.txt) it may be a *puq chonnaQ* (literally "child's spear").

Comment: The two-pronged skewer is the antecedent of the modern fork.  http://www.slate.com/content/dam/slate/articles/life/design/2012/06/Forks/two-pronged.jpg.CROP.article568-large.jpg  Heck, we still use them now for specific foods.  Thus, it's hardly a unique alien invention.

Comment: @Jules - An excellent find. I'm sure LevenTech won't mind me editing that into his answer.

Comment: @RonJohn - Sure, but it's a specific implement with a specific name. And they're hardly a common utensil, noting that the one you've pictured isn't for eating, it's for serving.

Comment: @Valorum the problem is that there are only so many ways for humanoids to shovel food into their pie-holes with relative efficiency.

Comment: @Jules If that's the literal translation of it - it does beg the question why any self-respecting warrior would be seen at a table using them...

Comment: @JonClements How honorable would it be to use your *real* weapons on prey that has already stopped moving>

Answer (score 10):

Star Trek shows plenty of alien foods, but I don't know that we ever see any alien utensils in an episode. Jonathan Archer had some... interesting cutlery in Enterprise ([Carbon Creek](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Carbon_Creek_(episode))), but you'll immediately recognize them as normal human utensils

[image]

Vulcans are mentioned in another episode as [never eating with their hands unless wearing gloves](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Vulcan#Culture_and_tradition), but the gloves are never shown in canon. Every other instance I can find is some "different" take on human stuff. Take this Lwaxana Troi shot of her holding some exotic fork. And [she's hardly the only one](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Fork)

[image]

Comment: Oh man, I _love_ how Memory Alpha has entries for Fork, Knife and Spoon.

Comment: @n_b And Chopsticks. And hairsticks. Memory Alpha is crazy complete...

Comment: See also [Category:Culinary tools](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Culinary_tools), which has lots of human stuff and... not much else.

Comment: This could be a pretty easy case of convergent design: since most Star Trek aliens are humanoid, they have basically the same design question: something you can grab with a hand and bring food to the mouth... and forks, knives, and spoons are pretty solid solutions to that problem. Vary in details, sure, but the basic shape could very well be the same.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe, and yet here on earth we're all actually humans and there's at least two alternatives to the knife/fork/spoon combination that are used by 100's of millions of us.

Comment: At the same time, the fork and spoon were independently invented in several human cultures at several points of time in history, and has seen pretty major success across the world. Even places with widely used alternatives such as China also invented their own forks and spoons and used them throughout history.

Comment: I appreciate that answer but think it was the scene in A Matter of Honor I had in mind.